# In Airflow,How can i create Workflow having multiple DAG that can be invoked by executing that workflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I have multiple DAG's created in Airflow .but i want to triggger all of them via some common Module or DAG .Can we create a workflow like Azkaban to have all the DAgs invoked listed in that flow.

Answer (score 0):

- You can create a `DAG` that triggers other `DAG`s using [`TriggerDagRunOperator`](https://incubator-airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/code.html#airflow.operators.dagrun_operator.TriggerDagRunOperator) by passing their `dag_id` and other appropriate args
- Source of the operator can be found in [`dagrun_operator.py`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py)

---

Also I suggest you go through the [Scheduling and Triggers](https://incubator-airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scheduler.html#scheduling-triggers) section of the docs

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SubdagOperator**.

- The main DAG see and manage all the SubDAGs as normal tasks
- the Airflow admin GUI list only the main DAG in the main DAGs list, then it will be possible to "zoom-in" to the SubDAG in the Graph View section of the GUI.
- We can manage all dags using its main dag or each sub-dags separately by going through its zoom-in option

here is an example for the operator:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_subdag_operator.py

> I recommended using a common dag factor to create all sub-dags if all
>   are in the same pattern and workflow.